# Lambda expressions in Java using predicate object in filter

Tags: java, lambda

This is simple code selecting a random subset of integers from a list of integers using lambda expressions. What the function is doing is, iterate through the list and for each element a random boolean value is called. Based on that element is selected or discarded.

```
public static List<Integer> getRandomSubsetUsingLambda(List<Integer> list) {
    List<Integer> randomSubset = new ArrayList<>();
    Random random = new Random();
    Predicate<Object> flipCoin = o -> {
        return random.nextBoolean();
    };

    randomSubset = list.stream().filter(flipCoin).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return randomSubset;
}
```

My understanding is that filter, based on ta boolean value selects the integers. But I didn't understand how is that happening. Does it mean that whenever flipCoin is called a boolean value is returned?

Comment: Add `System.out.println("flipCoing called for " + o);` just before `return random.nextBoolean();` in your lambda expression, then run your stream again. You'll see.

Answer (score 0):

filter() will call to flipCoin passing as parameter the iterated value from the stream.
Then flipCoin will generate a random boolean (ignoring the value of its parameter) and if false the iterated value from the stream will be discarded.

i.e. for each element in the stream a random boolean is generated and used to decide (randomly) if the element is accepted or discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Let's pick a practical example with a `List` containing three elements `[1, 2, 3]`

`1`

```
list.stream()
    .filter(flipCoin) // random.nextBoolean() returns true so 1 goes through
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // 1 is waiting to be added to the list
```

`2`

```
list.stream()
    .filter(flipCoin) // random.nextBoolean() returns false and 2 is blocked
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`3`

```
list.stream()
    .filter(flipCoin) // random.nextBoolean() returns true 
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // 3 is the last element of your stream so the list is created
```

The new `List` contains `[1, 3]`

Basically, everytime `filter(flipCoin)` is invoked, the following block code is executed for each `element` going through it (here `Integer`s)

```
public boolean test(Object o) {
    return random.nextBoolean();
}
```

---

Basically, your stream is the equivalent of the following code block

```
List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Integer i : list) {
    boolean shouldBeAddedToNewList = random.nextBoolean();
    if (shouldBeAddedToNewList) {
        newList.add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks.  One small doubt, I think the in the flipCoin lambda expression, 'o' is of type integer. So I could write Predicate<Integer> to be more precise. Please correct me if am wrong.